# jQUERY: nothing happens with .click(function() where am I going wrong?

Tags: jquery

Still learning jquery here and I've tried to setup a set of divs that expand and then close, however nothing is happening on the close. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/N6Jkw/

Thanks!

Comment: Because this will come up several times (and this is as much for those answering): as of jQuery 1.7 [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used in preference to `live()` [Reference: `live()` at jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: @DavidThomas, I can't upvote that enough!

Comment: anychance we could get an answer with the non-depreciated on() instead? just replacing .live with .on doesn't seem to work

Comment: `$("body").on('click','div.expand',function() {` and `$("body").on('click','span.close',function() {`. Read the documentation that was provided in the first comment.

Comment: thanks! if you made that an answer I'd award you the question since its the most current way of doing it.. also you wouldnt know why the cycle of 'expand' 'close' stops working (box is empty) after one try would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dynamically adding the `span.close` element.

So you need to use the [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) method to bind the events..

```
$("span.close").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('.post-big').hide();
    $(this).parent().prev().show();       
   });
```

Also note that i used `prev` as there is no next element (*and you seem to want to bring back the one you close earlier..*)..

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/N6Jkw/1/

Comment: thanks for the help, I did need .prev instead of .next, however, when you cycle thru from 'expand' to 'close' and back to 'expand', the box becomes empty and does not load the ajax request a second time. Any ideas why this would be????

Comment: @trying, this is because you hide the container.. check out http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/N6Jkw/3/ where i re-show the container each time you click on expand.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.close` `<div>`s are created dynamically, so you need to use `.live` - this will assign the `click` handler to every new `<div>` that's added to the DOM. See:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$("span.close").live("click", function() {
   $(this).parent('.post-big').hide();
   $(this).parent().next().show();       
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is *(finally)* deprecated. In any case, `.live()` doesn't assign anything to new elements added to the DOM. It assigns a handler to the `document` and uses event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to `$("span.close")`, the `<span>` is not in the DOM yet.  Try using `.live()` here.

```
$("span.close").live('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.post-big').hide();
  $(this).parent().next().show();       
});
```